# Access VBA: Select only multiple values

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Say, I have a table that looks like this:

```
ID | PNo | MM   | CP |
---|-----|------|----|
1  | 13  | True | 4  |
2  | 92  | True | 3  |
3  | 1   | True | 3  |
4  | 13  | False| 2  |
5  | 13  | True | 3  |
6  | 1   | True | 3  |
```

I want to go through all PNos and compare all rows with that PNo and only select those that have different values in field MM.

My plan was to create a table with the distinct values of PNo, iterate through that table by using the usual record set and write an SQL query for each PNo.
Now my problem is the construction of the SQL query.

I can select all rows with Table.PNo = rs("PNo") but I have no idea how to formulate the query to catch the rows with varying values.

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  Go through each `PNo` - so that's 1, 13 and 92.  Select those that have different values in `MM` -  MM is TRUE / FALSE.  So 1 only has TRUE so show nothing as nothing is different from that value?  92 has 1 record, so nothing is different from that value?  13 has TRUE and FALSE - as a boolean can only have TRUE and FALSE then nothing will be different from that either.. so show an empty table?

Comment: Sorry, it was probably not very clear.
I want to select rows with the ID 1, 4, 5 as they have two different values in MM: True and False. I do not want the rows with the ID 3, 6 as they only have True as value in MM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* this should work.

This will create a cartesian product on y our PNo field. i.e. Every record connected to every record (but just on that PNo).

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Table1 T1 INNER JOIN Table1 T2 ON T1.PNo = T2.PNo
```

You'll end up with 9 instances of PNo 13, 4 of 1 and 1 of 92.  Now we just want to return the ones where MM is different, so add that to the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Table1 T1 INNER JOIN Table1 T2 ON T1.PNo = T2.PNo
WHERE   T1.MM <> T2.MM
ORDER BY T1.ID
```

This will return four records.  `PNo` 1 and 92 will have vanished as the MM result was the same for those.  `ID` number 4 will be returned twice as the `MM` value is different from that in ID 1 and ID 5.

To remove the duplicate value you could then use DISTINCT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.ID, T1.PNo, T1.MM, T1.CP
FROM            Table1 T1 INNER JOIN Table1 T2 ON T1.PNo = T2.PNo
WHERE           T1.MM <> T2.MM
ORDER BY        T1.ID
```

**Note:**  One of the differences between the answer given by @Jonathan and mine is that his query is updateable and mine isn't.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery:

```
Select *
From YourTable
Where PNo IN 
    (Select T.PNo 
    From YourTable        
    Group By PNo, MM
    Having Count(*) = 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should do what you want:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE PNo in
(SELECT t.PNo FROM MyTable t 
INNER join  MyTable f
ON t.PNo = f.PNo
WHERE t.MM = true and f.MM = false)
```

The inner join ensures that only those PNos that have both MM false and MM true are included.